# Sending contact form data in PHP

Tags: php

I have launched my website. I am trying to send the data of two forms in email using PHP. It is working fine but the problem is that i receive all the data in single line. What i am trying to achieve is to have all data in email in line break. Below i am mentioning both forms PHP code. Kindly guide me where i am doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Form1:

```
<? php
($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
$ToEmail = 'info@ad4u.pk'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Website Contact form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "email: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "phone: ".nl2br($_POST["phone"])."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "message: ".nl2br($_POST["message"]);
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
echo "<script> alert('Messgae successfully sent!');
window.location='index.html'</script>";
   exit;  
?>
```

Form2:

```
<?php
($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
$ToEmail = 'info@ad4u.pk'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Website Price Inquiry form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Adress: ".nl2br($_POST["address"])."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "phone: ".nl2br($_POST["phone"])."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "product: ".nl2br($_POST["product"])."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "quantity: ".nl2br($_POST["quantity"]);
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
echo "<script> alert('Messgae successfully sent!');
window.location='index.html'</script>";
   exit;  
?>
```

Comment: wow- no filtering of submitted data! You leave yourself open to all sorts of unpleasantness by not cleansing POST data!

Comment: I see a few other minor issues as well: 1) I see no reason to use `text/html` as the Content-Type, you're not actually putting HTML into the document. 2) If you're using Postfix as the mail server, that actually expects the MIME line terminators to be those native to the underlying OS, so instead of `\r\n` at the end of each `$mailheader` item you'd use `PHP_EOL`. 3) Don't use JavaScript to create the pop-up and redirect, just hand-off to a messaging script using a PHP `header()` call (HTTP 302), if you output the `<script> ... ` to the browser it'll be cached and can be reloaded.

Comment: "Kindly edit the code for me" - we generally don't do that here. Readers are generally willing to assist, but not to work for free.

Answer (score 1):

1. replace `"\r\n"` with `"<br/>"` or
2. use [`nl2br($MESSAGE_BODY)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)  before mail();

Comment: ... or just set the `Content-Type` to text/plain.